# How do I align multiple elements inside a column?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I've got two objects inside a column (a paragraph and an image). I need the image at the bottom and the paragraph at the top. Sadly I can't find a bootstrap class that solves this problem. I thought "align-items-between" would do the job but it doesn't. "align-self-end" as a class for the image doesn't work either.

```
<div class="container">
    <h1 class="display-3 text-center mb-5">
        Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
    </h1>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <!-- I need this paragraph to stay at the top -->
            <p class="text-muted text-center">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis laudantium ducimus veritatis aliquam voluptas, maiores error inventore facere minus rem.
            </p>
            <!-- I need this image to be at the bottom of the container -->
            <img src="imgs/abc.svg" class="img-fluid" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <!-- Other stuff-->
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Here is an image of what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WwBpA.png)

Comment: so you want `img-fluid` after `"Other stuff"`?

Comment: I don't understand. HTML would do this on its own.

Comment: you can use `card` class for that, i think you need to share image of your need !

Comment: No, the first column with the paragraph and the image is on the left side (It's some Text with a rocket underneath) and on the right side ("other stuff") is a really long contact form i didn't want to include. i want the rocket to stay on the left side in it's column. I just want the paragraph to be at the top of that column and the image to be at the bottom.

Comment: sorry about the confusion guys... https://imgur.com/3zpIGrJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply the following class and styles to your first column:

```css
.space-between {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

[Example bootply](https://www.bootply.com/YpLLaBJV5X)

Please note I have fixed your closing tags for the first column in the bootply (you had nested the second column inside the first column in the code above)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing a closing `div` breaking the grid.

codepen: https://codepen.io/brooksrelyt/pen/JwQpqm

```
<div class="container">
    <h1 class="display-3 text-center mb-5">
        Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
    </h1>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <!-- I need this paragraph to stay at the top -->
            <p class="text-muted text-center">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis laudantium ducimus veritatis aliquam voluptas, maiores error inventore facere minus rem.
            </p>
            <!-- I need this image to be at the bottom of the container -->
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x100" class="img-fluid" alt="" />
<!--           <img src="imgs/abc.svg" class="img-fluid" alt="" /> -->
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <!-- Other stuff-->
              <p>Form other stuff</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want the image to be fixed to the bottom of the col?